# Celery doesn't work on docker

Tags: python, docker, celery

I have the problem to use celery in docker.

I configured two docker container, web_server and celery_worker. celery_worker includes rabbitmq-server. The web_server calls the task from celery worker.

I configured same thing in VM by vagrant. And it works. But docker speak out the error message like below.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/web_server/test/test_v1_data_description.py", line 58, in test_create_description
    headers=self.get_basic_header()

  .........
  .........

  File "../task_runner/__init__.py", line 31, in run_describe_task
    kwargs={})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 349, in send_task
    self.backend.on_task_call(P, task_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/backends/rpc.py", line 32, in on_task_call
    maybe_declare(self.binding(producer.channel), retry=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 194, in _get_channel
    channel = self._channel = channel()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 425, in __call__
    value = self.__value__ = self.__contract__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 209, in <lambda>
    channel = ChannelPromise(lambda: connection.default_channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 756, in default_channel
    self.connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 741, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 696, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 116, in establish_connection
    conn = self.Connection(**opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 165, in __init__
    self.transport = self.Transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 186, in Transport
    return create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 299, in create_transport
    return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise socket.error(last_err)
nose.proxy.OSError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

These are Dockerfiles for two containers.

Dockerfile for web_server.

```
 FROM ubuntu:14.04
 MAINTAINER Jinho Yoo 

 # Update packages.
 RUN apt-get clean
 RUN apt-get update

 # Create work folder.
 RUN mkdir /web_server
 WORKDIR /web_server

 # Setup web server and celery.
 ADD ./install_web_server_conf.sh ./install_web_server_conf.sh
 RUN chmod +x ./install_web_server_conf.sh
 RUN ./install_web_server_conf.sh

 #Reduce docker size.
 RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

 # Run web server.
 CMD ["python3","web_server.py"]

 # Expose port.
 EXPOSE 5000
```

Dockerfile for celery_worker.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Jinho Yoo 

# Update packages.
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget build-essential ca-certificates-java

# Setup python environment.
ADD ./bootstrap/install_python_env.sh ./install_python_env.sh
RUN chmod +x ./install_python_env.sh
RUN ./install_python_env.sh

# Install Python libraries including celery.
RUN pip3 install -r ./core/requirements.txt

# Add mlcore user for Celery worker
RUN useradd --uid 1234 -M mlcore
RUN usermod -L mlcore

# Celery configuration for supervisor
ADD celeryd.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celeryd.conf
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/celery

# Reduce docker size.
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Run celery server by supervisor.
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/ml_core/supervisord.conf"]

# Expose port.
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081
EXPOSE 4040
EXPOSE 7070
EXPOSE 5672
EXPOSE 5671
EXPOSE 15672
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. Docker container in `celery_worker` doesn't run `rabbitmq-server`.  So I added two lines in Dockerfile of `celery_worker` like below.

```
# Run rabbitmq server and celery.
ENTRYPOINT service rabbitmq-server start && supervisord -c /ml_core/supervisord.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers can't talk to each other normally. My guess is that your connection string is something like `localhost:<port>`?

There's a couple ways to have your containers be able to communicate.

1: linking
http://rominirani.com/2015/07/31/docker-tutorial-series-part-8-linking-containers/

essentially, at runtime, docker adds an entry into your hosts file that points to the internal IP address of the docker container within the same private docker network stack.

2: `docker run --net=host`:
this binds your containers to your host network stack, thus, all containers will appear to be running from `localhost`, and can be accessed as such. You may run into port conflict issues if you are running multiple containers that bind to the same external port, just be aware of that.

3: external HAProxy:
you can bind a DNS entry to an HAProxy, and config the proxy to redirect traffic with a hostheader that matches the DNS entry to the host:port your container is running on, and any calls from other containers will "leave" the private docker network stack, hit the DNS server, and circle back to the HAProxy, which will direct to the proper container.